# Differential equation system order $n$- exercice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have a difficulty in this problem.

Let the differential system order $n$ : $$ \dfrac{d X}{dt}=f(X)$$
with $X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

Prove that if we denote $\tau=t_2-t_1,$ then for any solution $X$ for this system satisfying $X(t_1)=X(t_2)$, we have $$X(t+\tau)=X(t)$$.
can you help me in 
[System Differential Equation - problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499967/system-differential-equation-problem)
please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, You have $\tau=t_2-t_1$,and $X(t_1)=X(t_2)$, replacing $t_2$ by $t_1$+$\tau$, we get $X(t_1)=X(t_1+\tau)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I edit my question and i write the exercice, completely. Can you help me please.

Comment: Thank you! can you help me to resolve the questions 2 ans 3 please.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the problem!
If the following condition is satisfied:
$ \dfrac{d X}{dt}=f(X)$
and we can find $t_1$ and $t_2$ that $X(t_1)=X(t_2)$, then we should prove that $x(t)$ is a periodic function.
So lets imagine that $t_1$ and $t_2$ create the smallest interval that:  $X(t_1)=X(t_2)$

Then(by intermediate theorem) we know that there exist a $t_c$ that $dX/dt = 0$ or $X(t_c)$ is maximum or minimum. In the case of maximum:
There exist a $t_k(t_1<t_k<t_c)$ that $X(t_1)<X(t_k)<X(t_c)$(by extreme value theorem) and also there exist a $t_l(t_c<t_l<t_2)$ that $X(t_2)<X(t_l)<X(t_c)$ in a way that $X(t_k)=X(t_l)$(by extreme value theorem).
this is a paradox cause we assumed $[t_1,t_2]$ is the smallest interval where $X$ has the same value($[t_k,t_l]$ is smaller interval). 
**I'm not sure if I'm right, maybe I'm missing something here.**

Comment: I edit my question and i write the exercice, completely. Can you help me please.

Comment: I need help please!

Answer (score 0):

I assume $X(t)$ is a vector.  Suppose $X(t_1)=X(t_2)=X_0$.  Let $Y(t)=X(t-\tau)$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are both solutions to 
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=f(X)\\X(t_2)=X_0$$
I forget the theorems that claim that there is only one solution to a first-order initial value differential equation (if $f$ is well-behaved).  They show that  $Y(t)$ and $X(t)$ are the same function, so $X(t)=Y(t)$ for all $t\ge t_2$

Comment: But there isn't an problem of Cauchy, and we don't have the hypothesis to caim the existence and unicity of solution.

Comment: can you help me in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499967/system-differential-equation-problem  please