# System Differential Equation - problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have a difficulty in this problem.Help me please.

Let the differential system order $n$ : $$ \dfrac{d X}{dt}=f(X)$$
with $X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

Prove that if we denote $\tau=t_2-t_1,$ then for any solution $X$ for this system satisfying $X(t_1)=X(t_2)$, we have $$X(t+\tau)=X(t)$$.

Let $K$ the set of real numbers $\tau$ such as $X(t+\tau)=X(t)$ holds.

2- Prouve that $K$ is additive group.

3- Puove that, if $K$ does not admit a minimum greater than 0, the solution is constant.

4- Deduce that the solution of this system have 3 possibilities: peridic, not periodic or probably constant.

Answer (score 0):

So, in plain words, you want to show that:

- If a solution comes full circle after some time $\tau$, it'll repeat the exact same timecourse it followed in the interval $[0,\tau]$;
- Any solution repeating itself after time $\tau$ and $\tau'$, will repeat itself after time $\tau+\tau'$;
- Either a minimum period exists or else the solution is constant.

For the first two, use the semigroup property.

For the third one, assume a non-constant solution & show that a minimum period exists: first, there exists $t_*>0$ s.t. $X(t_*) \ne X(0)$ (by assumption); second, $\inf_{t}[X(t) = X(t_*)]>0$ (by continuity of the solution); finally, $\tau>t_*>0$ for any period $\tau$ (or else a smaller $t_*$ within $[0,\tau]$ could be found).

NB: I haven't checked, but I've a feeling J. Hale's ODE book might be good reading material for such arguments.